# Angular JS - code that breaks the app in Safari and IE

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, safari

I have an app in Angular JS, I have some code which counts the characters from an array, the code below breaks the app and stops it from working in Safari and IE, I can't see whats wrong:

app.js

```
Object.defineProperty($scope, 'characters', {
        get() {
            return $scope.what.join('').length + $scope.why.join('').length;
        }
});
```

This code breaks the app in those two browsers?

Comment: supported browser version Internet Explorer 8.0+ & Safari 5.1.7+ , could you double check with that

Comment: I have already checked that... it does not work when this code is implemented...

Answer (score 0):

I've personally never seen that get() syntax before, but I spend most of my time trying to code stuff I know is safe.

It looks like you need to write your code like this:

```
Object.defineProperty($scope, 'characters', {
    get: function() {
        return $scope.what.join('').length + $scope.why.join('').length;
    }
});
```

[MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

Hope this helped.